# Работа с экселем в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Вопрос про параметр newline="", что именно он делает, как я понял убирает лишние строки при выводе в эксель (точнее в .csv), но откуда они там появляются при выводе?

Примеры кода:

```
with open (FILE, "w", newline="") as file:
writer = csv.writer (file)
writer.writerows (users)

with open (FILE, "w") as file:
writer = csv.writer (file)
writer.writerows (users)
```

[image: Вывод без параметра newline="" и с ним.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newline` Строка, определяющая режим работы универсальных переводов строк. Следует использовать только для текстовых файлов. Варианты: None, пустая строка, \n, \r, и \r\n. None — при чтении потока будут использованы универсальные переводы строк (\n, \r и \r\n будут преобразованы в \n); при записи — \n преобразуются в разделитель, используемый в системе (os.linesep). Пустая строка — при чтении также используются универсальные переводы строк, однако символы не будут преобразованы в \n; при записи преобразование не происходит. Другие значения — при чтении разбивка на строки осуществляется при помощи значения, преобразование не производится; при записи \n преобразуются в указанное значение.
[Источник](https://pythonz.net/references/named/open/)